# what's the best way to bind a mongodb doc to a node.js html page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

In past with my PHP / Rails - MYSQL apps I've used the unique ID of a table record to keep track of a record in an html file.

So I'd keep track of how to delete a record shown like this (15 being the ID of the record):

```
<a href="/profile/delete/15">Delete this record</a>
```

So now I'm using MongoDB. I've tried the same method but the objectID ._id attribute seems to be a loooong byte string that I can't use conveniently.

What's the most sensible way of binding a link in the view to a record (for deletion, or other purposes or whatever)?

If the answer is to create a new id that's unique for each document in the collection, then what's the best way to generate those unique id's?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a counter instead of the [ObjectID](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-SequenceNumbers)

But this could create a problem when inserting a new document after you deleted a previous one.
See this blog post for more detail info on [Sequential unique identifiers with Node.js and MongoDB](http://bravenewmethod.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/cached-sequential-unique-identifiers-with-node-js-and-mongodb/).

Or you could use the timestamp part of the ObjectID:

```
objectId.getTimestamp().toString()
```

[See the node objectid docs](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#gettimestamp)